# Reading the current fragment color in GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm trying to draw a circle on the screen, where the circle's color is always the opposite of the color of what was there before. Similar to the crosshairs in Minecraft, which are always a different color than what they are currently focused on. Is there a way to access the current fragment color in GLSL?

[image: Minecraft crosshairs]

Comment: The only thing I can imagine is to use [Blending](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Blending), with a blending equation like `GL_FUNC_SUBTRACT`. See [`glBlendEquationSeparate`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/GLAPI/glBlendEquationSeparate). But that depends on the context of your application. There is not enough information in your question to give a clear answer. But it is not possible to read from the framebuffer in the fragment shader.

Answer (score 1):

In GLSL, there is no such thing. I can think of  a couple of ways to achieve that effect in the GL:

1. as @Rabbid already suggestet in the comment, use [Blending](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Blending).
2. another seldom used feature of the GL  which *might* be able to achieve such an effect are the [Logical Operations](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Logical_Operation), which allow to define some bitwise operations between the incoming *source* color (the fragment shader's output) and the *destination* color in the framebuffer.
3. If you can use OpenGL 4.5 or the [`GL_ARB_TEXTURE_BARRIER`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_texture_barrier.txt), you can sample from the same texture you are writing to, if you only sample from exactly that texel the fragment shader will write to. So this is basically exactly what you asked for: you get the actual color value your framebuffer has, at that fragment's location, and can do whatever operation you like on it. It does require a render-to-texture setup, though.
4. Use render-to-texture in a multipass approach. First render your ordinary image to the texture, and in a separate pass, render to another render target and compose your objects with different color on top of it. This is quite similar to option 3, but does not require GL 4.5 or any advanced extensions, just OpenGL 3.0 or 2.x + FBO extensions will do.